# How to change Mvc Pie Chart colors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, charts, pie-chart

I have a chart typeo of pie and need to change the colors that used as default settings in Mvc chart !

This my chart series

```
<Series _Template_=""All"" 
ShadowOffset=""2"" 
BorderColor=""64, 64, 64"" 
BorderDashStyle=""Solid"" 
BorderWidth=""1"" 
Color=""189, 215, 191""
IsValueShownAsLabel=""false"" 
Font=""Hacen Typographer, 12pt, GdiCharSet=0"" 
LabelForeColor=""100, 100, 100"" 
CustomProperties=""DoughnutRadius=60, 
PieLabelStyle=Outside, 
PieDrawingStyle=SoftEdge"" 
ChartType=""pie"" />
```

As string, So where could I set colore for each pie point or part !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it...

I use this a them liek

> "
>
> ```
> <ChartArea Name=""Default"" _Template_=""All"" 
>
>     BackColor=""Transparent"" BackSecondaryColor=""White"" BorderDashStyle=""Solid"" ShadowColor=""Transparent"">
>
>   <AxisY>
>
>     <LabelStyle Font=""Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"" />
>
>   </AxisY>
>
>   <AxisX LineColor=""64, 64, 64, 64"">
>
>     <LabelStyle Font=""Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"" />
>
>   </AxisX>
>
> </ChartArea>
> ```
>
> ```
> <Legend _Template_=""All"" BackColor=""Transparent"" Docking=""Bottom"" Font=""Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold""
> ```
>
> LegendStyle=""Row"">
>
> ```
> </Legend>
> ```
>
> "

The key to colorize the pie is to change here

```
PaletteCustomColors=""180, 189,175;134,192, 106;189, 215, 121""
```

Add even color RGB as you need :)

Comment: Where you add PaletteCustomColors ?

Answer (score 0):

Palette shoud be set to None for this to work

```
<Chart PaletteCustomColors=""180, 189,175;134,192, 106;189, 215, 121"" Palette=""None"">
```